# Viual Studio 2019 - C++ - adding DLL reference - Add reference dialog is empty

Tags: visual-studio, c++, dll

I try to add DLLs to a project, the project itself runs fine but at runtime it does not find the DLL in VS2017. I just had to copy the DLLs with the source files but here I just cannot find how it works.

I included the DLLs as part of the solution and rebuilt it, same problem.

I read many posts that say I should use "Add Reference" but the dialog does not show any item nor any browse button

**Edit:** I try using the NuGet installer, but it's hard to figure which version of what to install.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a browse button in your add references dialog box by following the below steps:

- to go **Project properties**
- under **configuration properties** -> click the small arrow towards left which gives more options under configuration properties and select **advanced**.
- under advanced -> you will find an option called **Common Language Runtime Support** -> which will be none -> change it by clicking the down arrow and select the option **Common Language runtime support(/clr)** -> apply -> ok

Now the browse button appears in the add reference dialog and add reference to your project.

PS: I have used Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Thank you!  This is far more helpful than the Microsoft documentation note that you might not see the "Browse" option!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile and run the code with NuGet package manager

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: OR - upvote another answer and check as answered.